# Drawing UIImage at multiple locations in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm kind of lost in between UIImage, UIImageView, CG, layers... 
I want to draw the same UIImage multiple times in the same UIImageView. I don't want to have a separate subview for each of those objects. It's enough to have a flat image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView does not allow you to do that. Instead, I would recommend you to use a regular UIView and use the drawRect: function to draw the images. Take a look at the Core Graphics docs if you want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

i found this as i was also looking for answers to this question

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/drawing-on-uiimages/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create multiple `UIImage` objects to do this.   Really a `UIImageView` is the wrong choice.  Create a `UIView` and just add mulitple `UIImageView` objects to it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess it is simple

```
[imageView addSubview:myTextView];
```

where myTextView  can  be made using the following piece of code

```
UIImage *myImage = [[uiimage alloc]initwithname:@"txtImage"];
UIImageView *myTextView =
      [[UIImageView alloc]initwithframe:("enter the height width you want ")];
```